# getTime() returns only minutes and seconds

Tags: java, time

I have a problem with getting whole time in milliseconds from Date format.

My code looks something like that:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String remainedTime = ("01:48:30");
Date remainedTimeDate = sdf.parse(remainedTime);
```

remainedTimeDate.getTime() returns 2912000 but it should returns 6512000. It looks like only minutes and second are parsed but remainedTimeDate prints out correct date - Thu Jan 01 01:48:32 CET 1970

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's your timezone?

Comment: Don't try to model a duration with a `Date`: it's just not the right model. Use a `java.time.Duration`.

Comment: I got this output Thu Jan 01 01:48:30 GMT 1970   (6510000) , i don't see anything wrong in that code

Answer (score 1):

getTime() returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT, note the GMT, you are using CET timezone (+1 in January)